# Is someone leaning on the triage audit button?

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits, triage

Since yesterday, I'm getting one audit for every 10 reviews or so.

I should note that I'm an enthusiastic user of 'skip' -- if the question is not in my wheelhouse, I skip it, I don't spend time considering.

Comment: 1 audit for every 10 reviews?  That's not a *bad* clip; keeps one on their toes more often.

Comment: Are you handling all the audits or noticing them and skipping them?

Comment: I go ahead and mark them spam; most of them are grossly, obviously, spam.

Comment: I have that same feeling in the CVQ, too much skipping gives you more audits.

Comment: Fooie. 75% of triage is PHP, about which I know nothing, so I skip.

Comment: I'll make it easy for you: whenever you see a PHP question in triage, it's probably unsalvageable.

Comment: @BoltClock both funny, and unfortunately, true.

Comment: @BoltClock: `s/ in triage//`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin `s/\ba //` `s/ question in triage//`

Comment: I know nothing about PHP, I just know it's fun to bash.

Comment: How do you do PHP from a bash script?

Comment: @Almo, with the ``php`` command, obviously.

Comment: @mmdeas, @Almo, True, but a more specific example would be: `echo "<?php print('Kill me now')?>" | php`

Comment: @KyleStrand PHP has the same problems as jQuery: it's very easy to (mis)use. I like to think of myself as a *good* user of PHP, but then I look at code I wrote a month ago and recoil...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I just remember the "double-clawed hammer": http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-php-singularity/

Comment: Rule of thumb: If it contains a phone number or an email address that is not part of the question, it is probably spam.